# splash screen won't show

Tags: xcode

EDIT 1: changed the code to:

delegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    ViewController *viewController;
    UIImageView *splashView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet ViewController *viewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *splashView;

- (void)removeSplash;

@end
```

delegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize viewController;
@synthesize splashView;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    splashView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Splash" ofType:@"png"]];
    [window addSubview:splashView];
    [window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [self performSelector:@selector(removeSplash) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];

    [window addSubview:viewController.view];

    return YES;
}

- (void)removeSplash {
    [splashView removeFromSuperview];
    [splashView release];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [viewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

EDIT 2:

when I use:

```
splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
splashView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Splash" ofType:@"png"]];
if (splashView.image == nil) {
    NSLog(@"splashView is nil");
}
```

it logs "splashView is nil"

My Viewcontroller is empty, just for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably already know, splash screens are discouraged.  Since your image is Default.png, isn't it already being shown on app launch automatically?

In any case, the sleep() call is probably blocking the UI.  Remove the sleep() and move the statements after it (the removeFromSuperview, etc) to another method in the app delegate.  Call this method using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.  Put the performSelector call where you currently have the sleep call.

Also, you should use the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method instead of the old applicationDidFinishLaunching method.

Comment: Although splash screens are discouraged, if your app takes more than a second or two to load I think it is good UI to make sure it doesn't look like it can be interacted with.  A smaller alert splash-screen over your UI looks pretty good.

Comment: The Default.png doesn't work automatically when i just put it in my resource folder. Im trying your other solutions as we speak.

Comment: Also move the `[window addSubview:viewController.view];` to the `removeSplash` method (make it the last line in that method).

Comment: the background turned from black to white, but still no image

Comment: Is the background of your viewcontroller white?  Did you move the adding of the viewcontroller.view to removeSplash?  Is there a 5 second delay?  Make sure image is actually loading by checking if splashView.image is nil.

Comment: first the background is white(first it was black), then after 5 seconds it turns grey(background of the viewcontroller). I did move the viewcontroller.view to removeSplash. Where do i need to make this nil check?

Comment: After the imageWithContentsOfFile line.  Make sure you've added that image to your project and it is named exactly Splash.png.

Comment: Im very sure it is in my resource folder and in the project and named exactly Splash.png

Comment: The white background is the splashView object with no image.  It is not able to load Splash.png for some reason.  Try removing it from the project and add back.  Try another image you have in your project that you are using for another imageview.

Comment: ok any other image works just fine. can't figure out why my Splash.png doesn't

Comment: Ok so i opened the image in photoshop and i saved it again as Splash.png and now it works for some strange reason.... Anyway you've been a great help and because of you i've been able to solve this problem, THNX